# Leibniz's Theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, differential-geometry, flow, calculus

[image: Question is here]

I'm not familiar with Leibniz's Theorem, and by the time I added my substitutions, I got lost in the variables and how they are suppose to transform. Please help?

Comment: Have you looked here: @ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: None of these examples have one-dimensional cases like this one

Comment: You may want to write out the continuity equation for $\rho$ and think about whether it could be used here.

Comment: As a material derivative maybe?

Comment: This question is better suited for [the math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Nitpick: It is *Leibniz* - without a t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know the inner workings of the Leibniz integral rule to prove the proposition, but I encourage you to look at its derivation. Substitute $F = \rho f$ into the given equation to get \begin{align*}
\frac{D}{Dt}\int_{\mathcal{V}(t)}\rho fd\mathcal{V} &= \int_{\mathcal V} \left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\rho f) + \nabla\cdot(\rho f \boldsymbol{u}) \right]d\mathcal{V}\\
&= \int_{\mathcal V} \left[ \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}f + \rho\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \nabla f\cdot(\rho \boldsymbol{u}) + f\nabla \cdot(\rho \boldsymbol{u}) \right]d\mathcal{V}\\
&= \int_{\mathcal V} \left[ f\left(\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot(\rho \boldsymbol{u})\right) + \rho\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \nabla f\cdot\boldsymbol{u}\right)\right ]d\mathcal{V}.
\end{align*}
Then, the first term of the integrand becomes zero because of the continuity equation and the second term is just $\rho\, Df/Dt$ by definition.